# How to extract text values from html file to express js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm just trying to get the values from html text field and assigning the values into variables.

I need html to get all these values and post back the response somewhere in the .html file.

**html:**

```
 <body>
            <form>
                <label for="stageURL">Stage URL:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="stageURL" name="stageURL"><br>
                <label for="prodURL">Production URL:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="prodURL" name="prodURL">
              </form>
              <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </body>
```

**Express.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
const port = 3000;

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html')); // The user will see the html file in this path.
    let stageUrl = req.query.stageURL; //Need to fetch the input field data.
    let prodUrl = req.query.prodURL; // Need to fetch input field data.
    res.send(stageUrl+" : "+prodUrl); //print it back somewhere in the html file.
  });
```

**html view:**

[image]

I want to show the above html page when user tried to hit http://localhost:3000
and I just need to get the stage and prod url when the user click submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a templating engine like ejs. First you install ejs using the command below:

```bash
npm install ejs
```

Then you can set it up in your Express server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

let stageURL = '';
let prodURL = '';

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // The `index` here refers to the file in `views/index.ejs`
  stageURL = req.query.stageURL || stageURL;
  prodURL = req.query.prodURL || prodURL;
  res.render('index', { stageURL, prodURL });
});
```

After that, your `index.html` should be renamed to `views/index.ejs`:

```html
<body>
  <form method="get" action="/">
    <label for="stageURL">Stage URL:</label><br />
    <input
      type="text"
      id="stageURL"
      name="stageURL"
      value="<%= stageURL %>"
    /><br />
    <label for="prodURL">Production URL:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="prodURL" name="prodURL" value="<%= prodURL %>" />
    <br/>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

For more information about how to use EJS, you can refer to the guides here:

- https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-ejs-template-node-js-application/
- https://ejs.co/

Comment: I want to get the text value from the .html file and want to store that value for further use in the index.js file. Like if user entered xyz.paypal.prd.env.com in the prodURL field then I want to get that dynamic value from the .html file when user click submit button.

Comment: Hi @ArrchanaMohan, updated to include such logic, but do note that the value is now save at memory and will be cleared when you restart your Express server. You can consider to save it somewhere permanently